# How to create multiple language versions web?

Tags: language-agnostic

Hey, my clients want me to create more language versions of already existing website and I'd like to make it the right way ... all I can think of is to create a folder named 'DE' for example and copy the website in there, but it seems hard to manege, if I had to change something in design and so on. How would you do it?

Comment: You are right that there are certainly better ways than cutting-and-pasting, but to help more we need to know what environment you're using.

Comment: Is this a static or content managed web site?

Comment: It's kind of dynamic (in php) .. there are a lot of pages, where the php shows content from database.

Comment: exactly got the same question, and similar situation (many pages, kind of dynamic, php). one thing I have in mind is to have something like an excel  table in which all my sentences/words are translated in different columns, and then *some kind of things* that makes each sentence/word fit the correct item depending on user settings, and defaults to english when translation doens... that would be so nice. I would like simplicity but I would rather have robustness and stability

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a perfect translation, bear in mind [Google](http://translate.google.com/translate_tools?hl=en&layout=1&eotf=1&sl=es&tl=en) (and others) will let you put links on your site to dynamically translate the content for free.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly. Are we talking about static site or about dynamic content like PHP etc.

For dynamic content: look to externalize strings. seperate them from your source code and place them in localization file. Then include some logic to load the correct localization file according to the language attribute in the request coming from the users browser.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to create a website with managable localization can depend on the platform on which your website is being served from. Almost every single server platform has their fair share of tools and methods in implementing 'localization', so the question is what is your server platform?

Of course there are tools like Google's advanced language tools that will allow you to localize your website content using a few well placed links. Example: http://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&sl=en&tl=de&u=https://stackoverflow.com/&rurl=translate.google.com&usg=ALkJrhhs-9TKIfMRTZzSTobejHAlRfurVg